# linux replacing code in all files

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace, debian-7.6.0

The system is Linux Debian 7 32bit.

I have problem when I try to replace some codes in all files in the same folder.

The file names for example is:

```
--ADBCABCD-.html

ABCDABCD.html
```

for example I want replace code < script > with < iframe >
the command for replace

```
sed -i "s|< script >|< iframe >|g" *
```

I see this problem after I do this command

```
sed: invalid option -- 'A'
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...
```

this because the files name Contain `--` and `-`

same this file name `--ADBCABCD-.html`

please how I fix this problem I have a lot of files name Contain `--` and `-`

Comment: I thought "cant' you escape the dashes, or enclose in single quotes" but those failed for a `--weird` named file...

Answer (score 2):

Use a `--` option. This is the most prevalent option in most Unix utilities.

```
sed -i -- 's/input/output/g' *
       ^^
```

Alternatively, while using glob for matching, add the directory prefix:

```
sed -i 's/aaa/bbb/' ./*
```

No one will treat `./--` as an option, right?

Comment: the problem still the same

Comment: thanks you very very much for the help                         i fixed the code now   the code is  :    sed -i -- "s|<script>|<iframe>|g" *